# Object in object javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my problem, I would like to create a list of seasons with several episodes inside this way:

```
saisons[1] = [{episode: 1, file: "/"}, {episode: 2, file: "/"}, {episode: 3, file: "/"}];

saisons[2] = [{episode: 1, file: "/"}, {episode: 2, file: "/"}, {episode: 3, file: "/"}];
```

And accessible by making **saisons[1][2].file** for episode 2 of season 1.

I started doing this but it does not work...

```
var saisons = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
        var saison = 1;
    var select = { 
       saison:saison, 
       episode: i
     };
    if(typeof saisons[saison] === "undefined"){
      saisons[saison] = select;
    }else{
        var selects = [];
      selects.push(saisons[saison][0]);
      selects.push(saisons[saison][1]);
      selects.push(select);
      saisons[saison] = selects;
    }
}

console.log(saisons);
```

Would you have a solution or leads to my problems?

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed. The second item in the array is at index 1.

Comment: did you know that adding items in array using JS is done by `array.push(newItem)` ?

Comment: Can you show the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `[1]` to be the 1ˢᵗ, you need to shift the array by ignoring the 1ˢᵗ item (let assign `null` to the 1ˢᵗ item)

```js
// Prepare your seasons' array with predefined size . 
const saisons = Array.from({length: 5}, (v, k) => null);

// add seasons  : 

saisons[1] = [null ,{episode: 1, file: "/"}, {episode: 2, file: "/"}, {episode: 3, file: "/"}];

saisons[2] = [null, {episode: 1, file: "/"}, {episode: 2, file: "/"}, {episode: 3, file: "/"}];


//Print the 2ⁿᵈ episode of th 1ˢᵗ season :

console.log(
   saisons[1][2].file
)
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I do not understand much this code but I will try to try. One last question, how to add the episodes one by one with a loop in Season 1, for example?